# Simplify nested if else statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list, if-statement

I'm currently doing a body mass index calculation using html css and javascipt (using jquery library). In javascript or other programming language, how can I simplify multiple nested if else statement? The code works well, but I'm curious about another efficient method (maybe array or list?) to reduce working.

```
if (age < 18){

   if (age == 9){
       if (bmi < 14){
           $(".Classification").text(underweight)
       }
       else if (bmi < 18.6){
           $(".Classification").text(healthy)
       }
       else if (bmi < 21){
           $(".Classification").text(overweight)
       }
       else if (bmi >= 21){
           $(".Classification").text(obese)
       }
   }
   else if (age == 10){
       if (bmi < 14.2){
           $(".Classification").text(underweight)
       }
       else if (bmi < 19.4){
           $(".Classification").text(healthy)
       }
       else if (bmi < 22.2){
           $(".Classification").text(overweight)
       }
       else if (bmi >= 22.2){
           $(".Classification").text(obese)
       }
   }
   else if (age == 11){
       if (bmi < 14.6){
           $(".Classification").text(underweight)
       }
       else if (bmi < 20.2){
           $(".Classification").text(healthy)
       }
       else if (bmi < 23.2){
           $(".Classification").text(overweight)
       }
       else if (bmi >= 23.2){
           $(".Classification").text(obese)
       }
   }
   else if (age == 12){
       if (bmi < 15){
           $(".Classification").text(underweight)
       }
       else if (bmi < 21){
           $(".Classification").text(healthy)
       }
       else if (bmi < 24.2){
           $(".Classification").text(overweight)
       }
       else if (bmi >= 24.2){
           $(".Classification").text(obese)
       }
   }
   else if (age == 13){
       if (bmi < 15.4){
           $(".Classification").text(underweight)
       }
       else if (bmi < 21.8){
           $(".Classification").text(healthy)
       }
       else if (bmi < 25.2){
           $(".Classification").text(overweight)
       }
       else if (bmi >= 25.2){
           $(".Classification").text(obese)
       }
   }
   else if (age == 14){
       if (bmi < 16){
           $(".Classification").text(underweight)
       }
       else if (bmi < 22.6){
           $(".Classification").text(healthy)
       }
       else if (bmi < 26){
           $(".Classification").text(overweight)
       }
       else if (bmi >= 26){
           $(".Classification").text(obese)
       }
   }
   else if (age == 15){
       if (bmi < 16.6){
           $(".Classification").text(underweight)
       }
       else if (bmi < 23.4){
           $(".Classification").text(healthy)
       }
       else if (bmi < 26.8){
           $(".Classification").text(overweight)
       }
       else if (bmi >= 26.8){
           $(".Classification").text(obese)
       }
   }
   else if (age == 16){
       if (bmi < 17.2){
           $(".Classification").text(underweight)
       }
       else if (bmi < 24.2){
           $(".Classification").text(healthy)
       }
       else if (bmi < 27.6){
           $(".Classification").text(overweight)
       }
       else if (bmi >= 27.6){
           $(".Classification").text(obese)
       }
   }
   
   else if (age == 17){
       if (bmi < 17.8){
           $(".Classification").text(underweight)
       }
       else if (bmi < 24.8){
           $(".Classification").text(healthy)
       }
       else if (bmi < 28.2){
           $(".Classification").text(overweight)
       }
       else if (bmi >= 28.2){
           $(".Classification").text(obese)
       }
   }
   else{
       $(".Classification").text("age out of range")
   }


} else if (age >= 18) {

   if (bmi < 18.5){
       $(".Classification").text(underweight)
   }
   else if (bmi < 25){
       $(".Classification").text(healthy)
   }
   else if (bmi < 30){
       $(".Classification").text(overweight)
   }
   else if (bmi < 35){
       $(".Classification").text(obeseI)
   }
   else if (bmi < 40){
       $(".Classification").text(obeseII)
   }
   else if (bmi >= 40){
       $(".Classification").text(obeseIII)
   }

} else {
   $(".Classification").text("null")
}
```

Comment: As your code works, you could try: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: tbh, if I was reviewing this code for one of my team members I would initially have an issue with the nested if/else statements but after working through it I would realize this is "sadly" probably the most elegant way of doing it.  Part of code reviews is the ability to read and understand the code.  In this case... its easy to read and understand.  Because its basically "math", it might be good to comment the math calculations so that others will understand it.  Otherwise seems fine.

Comment: Making the age/classification into a function and returning the text from that function would substantially reduce the `$(".Classification").text(` entries and make it reusable (so it could go in something other than `.Classification`).

Comment: An object that defines the age/range may make the code *substantially* shorter and more maintainable (easier to add/change the values), but possibly hard to read/understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be simplified quite a bit if you supply a nested array with the "decision points":

```js
function bmi(age,b) {
  const text=["underweight","healthy","overweight","obese","obese II","obese III"],
        o={9:[14,   18.6, 21          ],
          10:[14.2, 19.4, 22.2        ],
          11:[14.6, 20.2, 23.2        ],
          12:[15,   21,   24.2        ],
          13:[15.4, 21.8, 25.2        ],
          14:[16,   22.6, 26          ],
          15:[16.6, 23.4, 26.8        ],
          16:[17.2, 24.2, 27.6        ],
          17:[17.8, 24.8, 28.2        ],
          18:[18.5, 25,   30,  35,  40]};
  let sc=o[Math.min(age,18)];
  if (!sc) return "too young for BMI";
  let i=sc.findIndex(v=>v>b);
  if (i==-1) i=sc.length
  return text[i]
}
const tests=[[8,18],[12,23],[13,25],[14,26],[15,27],[16,16],[17,22],[22,42]];
tests.forEach(([age,b])=>console.log(age+"y, bmi="+b+" : "+bmi(age,b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to simplify/beautify `if` statements is to use `switch` statements

For javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: New to SO, never trying to help again.

Comment: *never trying to help again* can certainly understand that reaction :(

Comment: @MiguelCardoso, didn't down-vote, but this is not an _answer_. This should instead be posted as a comment.

Comment: Miguel, its downvoted because this does not answer the OP's question.  However I removed my downvote in hopes that perhaps, you can show a code example of how a Javascript Case statement will work with this type of issue.