# How do I change information in textboxes depending on patient weight value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried multiple times now using both eventlisteners, onchange and oninput function-calls in the HTML and googling for days without finding a solution to my problem. I've tried to call a return at the end of the function, but that errors out due to it going infinite. I am a beginner at programmins using JS, so I am now coming to you guys and gals for help.

What I am trying to do is make the textbox update depending on a weight-input. I have a function (**estVentilasjon**) containing many "else ifs" to determine what the data input should be for the textboxes depending on what the patient weight is. But when I try to change the patient weight (**id vekt**) in real-time it doesn't rerun the function, and it will only work if I refresh the page.

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be higly appreciated.

```js
const months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

function ageCalculate() {
  let today = new Date();
  let inputDate = new Date(document.getElementById("fdato").value);
  let birthMonth, birthDate, birthYear;
  let birthDetails = {
    date: inputDate.getDate(),
    month: inputDate.getMonth() + 1,
    year: inputDate.getFullYear()
  };
  let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
  let currentMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  let currentDate = today.getDate();

  leapChecker(currentYear);

  if (
    birthDetails.year > currentYear ||
    (birthDetails.month > currentMonth && birthDetails.year == currentYear) ||
    (birthDetails.date > currentDate && birthDetails.month == currentMonth && birthDetails.year == currentYear)
  ) {
    displayResult("-", "-", "-");
    return;
  }

  birthYear = currentYear - birthDetails.year;

  if (currentMonth >= birthDetails.month) {
    birthMonth = currentMonth - birthDetails.month;
  } else {
    birthYear--;
    birthMonth = 12 + currentMonth - birthDetails.month;
  }

  if (currentDate >= birthDetails.date) {
    birthDate = currentDate - birthDetails.date;
  } else {
    birthMonth--;
    let days = months[currentMonth - 2];
    birthDate = days + currentDate - birthDetails.date;
    if (birthMonth < 0) {
      birthMonth = 11;
      birthYear--;
    }
  }
  displayResult(birthDate, birthMonth, birthYear);
  estWeight(birthDate, birthMonth, birthYear);
}

function displayResult(bDate, bMonth, bYear) {
  if (bYear >= 1) {
    document.getElementById("alder").value = bYear + " år " + bMonth + " måneder";
  } else if (bMonth >= 1) {
    document.getElementById("alder").value = bMonth + " måneder";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("alder").value = bDate + " dager";
  }
}

function leapChecker(year) {
  if (year % 4 == 0 || (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)) {
    months[1] = 29;
  } else {
    months[1] = 28;
  }
}

function estWeight(bDate, bMonth, bYear) {
  if (bYear >= 5) {
    document.getElementById("estvekt").value = 4 * bYear;
  } else if (bYear >= 1) {
    document.getElementById("estvekt").value = 2 * bYear + 5;
  } else if (bYear <= 1) {
    document.getElementById("estvekt").value = bMonth + 9 / 2;
  }
}

var vektventilasjon = document.getElementById("vekt").value;

function estVentilasjon() {
  if (vektventilasjon >= 2 && vektventilasjon < 3) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "35";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "525";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "15";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 3 && vektventilasjon < 4) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "35";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "700";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "20";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 4 && vektventilasjon < 5) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "34";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "1020";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "30";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 5 && vektventilasjon < 6) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "33";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "1155";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "35";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 6 && vektventilasjon < 7) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "33";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "1485";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "45";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 7 && vektventilasjon < 8) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "32";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "1600";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "50";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 8 && vektventilasjon < 9) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "31";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "1860";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "60";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 9 && vektventilasjon < 10) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "31";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "2015";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "65";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 10 && vektventilasjon < 12) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "30";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "2250";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "75";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 12 && vektventilasjon < 14) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "29";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "2610";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "90";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 14 && vektventilasjon < 16) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "27";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "2700";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "100";
  }
}


function callCalculations() {
  ageCalculate();
  estWeight();
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.4fr 1.2fr 1.4fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 5px 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "Blank Content Inputinfo" "Blank Content Suggested";
}

.Content {
  grid-area: Content;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.Inputinfo {
  grid-area: Inputinfo;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}

.Suggested {
  grid-area: Suggested;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

.Header {
  grid-area: Header;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

html,
header,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* Style the top navigation bar */

.topnav {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(21, 42, 67, 1), rgba(88, 159, 209, 1));
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: justify;
  clear: left;
  width: 125px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 2px;
}

input {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: justify;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}


/* Style the footer */

.footer {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Barneanestesi legemiddelkalkulator</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <h1>Velkommen til barneanestesi legemiddelkalkulatoren!</h1>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="Content">
      <span class="Ventilasjon">
      <p><b><u>Ventilasjon</u></b></p>
      <label for="tv"><b>Tidalvolum:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="tv" name="tv"<br>
      <label for="frekv"><b>Frekvens:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="frekv" name="frekv"><br>
      <label for="minvol"><b>Min volum:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="minvol" name="minvol"><br>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="Inputinfo">
      <label for="gutt"><i class="material-icons">male</i><b>Gutt</b></label>
      <input type="radio" id="gutt" name="gender" value="Gutt">
      <label for="jente"><i class="material-icons">female</i><b>Jente</b></label>
      <input type="radio" id="jente" name="gender" value="Jente">
      <label for="initialer"><i class="material-icons">assignment</i><b>Initialer:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="initialer" name="initialer"><br>
      <label for="fdato"><i class="material-icons">cake</i><b>Fødselsdato:</b></label>
      <input type="date" id="fdato" name="fdato" oninput="callCalculations()" required><br>
      <label for="diagnose"><i class="material-icons">search</i><b>Diagnose:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="diagnose" name="diagnose"><br>
      <label for="operasjon"><i class="material-icons">local_hospital</i><b>Operasjon:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="operasjon" name="operasjon"><br>
      <label for="hoyde"><i class="material-icons">person_outline</i><b>Høyde (cm):</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="hoyde" name="hoyde"><br>
      <label for="Vekt"><i class="material-icons">monitor_weight</i><b>Vekt (kg):</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="vekt" name="vekt" value="" oninput="estVentilasjon()">
      <label for="Faste"><i class="material-icons">fastfood</i><b>Faste fra:</b></label>
      <input type="time" id="faste" name="faste">
    </div><br>
    <div class="Suggested">
      <label for="alder"><i class="material-icons">cake</i><b>Alder:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="alder" name="alder">
      <label for="estvekt"><i class="material-icons">monitor_weight</i><b>Estimert vekt:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="estvekt" name="estvekt">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./ba.js"></script>

  <div class="footer">

  </div>
```

Comment: You need to retrieve the value of the input *in* the function: you retrieve it before any handlers have run and never update it.

Comment: I thought using the "document.getElementById" retrieved the value after the user input it in the textbox since the call for the function within the HTML is oninput. Would I need to make a eventlistener before my function, calling the eventlistener instead, then the function? I am quite new to JS, so I might need a bit more nudging in the right direction if you don't mind. Highly appreciate the answer though!

Comment: In addition to what @DaveNewton commented I would like to add, that there are quite a few DRY (dont't repeat yourself) issues with your code. E. g. the lines `document.getElementById("...")` appear many times and could have been evaluated *before* the `if .. else if() ... else if() ...` section.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann There probably is, but I am not too savvy yet in the art of programming. I guess I could have stored the information in a array of sorts, but I don't know how. So my code is how I sorta knew how to do it. Do you have any suggestions for further reading or what topic I should investigate to do this in a better practice manner? All help is appreciated!

Comment: I answered a similar question a while back, maybe this will give you some inspiration? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68071020/2610061

Comment: Beautiful looking code! I will give it a look, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById(xxx).value` gets the value at the time it's called.

You want its value when `estVentilasjon` is run: move the line that retrieves the value down a few lines so it's the first line in `estVentilasjon`.

I didn't look at any other code so I don't know if the rest of it is correct.

```js
const months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

function ageCalculate() {
  let today = new Date();
  let inputDate = new Date(document.getElementById("fdato").value);
  let birthMonth, birthDate, birthYear;
  let birthDetails = {
    date: inputDate.getDate(),
    month: inputDate.getMonth() + 1,
    year: inputDate.getFullYear()
  };
  let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
  let currentMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  let currentDate = today.getDate();

  leapChecker(currentYear);

  if (
    birthDetails.year > currentYear ||
    (birthDetails.month > currentMonth && birthDetails.year == currentYear) ||
    (birthDetails.date > currentDate && birthDetails.month == currentMonth && birthDetails.year == currentYear)
  ) {
    displayResult("-", "-", "-");
    return;
  }

  birthYear = currentYear - birthDetails.year;

  if (currentMonth >= birthDetails.month) {
    birthMonth = currentMonth - birthDetails.month;
  } else {
    birthYear--;
    birthMonth = 12 + currentMonth - birthDetails.month;
  }

  if (currentDate >= birthDetails.date) {
    birthDate = currentDate - birthDetails.date;
  } else {
    birthMonth--;
    let days = months[currentMonth - 2];
    birthDate = days + currentDate - birthDetails.date;
    if (birthMonth < 0) {
      birthMonth = 11;
      birthYear--;
    }
  }
  displayResult(birthDate, birthMonth, birthYear);
  estWeight(birthDate, birthMonth, birthYear);
}

function displayResult(bDate, bMonth, bYear) {
  if (bYear >= 1) {
    document.getElementById("alder").value = bYear + " år " + bMonth + " måneder";
  } else if (bMonth >= 1) {
    document.getElementById("alder").value = bMonth + " måneder";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("alder").value = bDate + " dager";
  }
}

function leapChecker(year) {
  if (year % 4 == 0 || (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)) {
    months[1] = 29;
  } else {
    months[1] = 28;
  }
}

function estWeight(bDate, bMonth, bYear) {
  if (bYear >= 5) {
    document.getElementById("estvekt").value = 4 * bYear;
  } else if (bYear >= 1) {
    document.getElementById("estvekt").value = 2 * bYear + 5;
  } else if (bYear <= 1) {
    document.getElementById("estvekt").value = bMonth + 9 / 2;
  }
}


function estVentilasjon() {
var vektventilasjon = document.getElementById("vekt").value;

  if (vektventilasjon >= 2 && vektventilasjon < 3) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "35";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "525";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "15";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 3 && vektventilasjon < 4) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "35";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "700";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "20";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 4 && vektventilasjon < 5) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "34";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "1020";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "30";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 5 && vektventilasjon < 6) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "33";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "1155";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "35";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 6 && vektventilasjon < 7) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "33";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "1485";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "45";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 7 && vektventilasjon < 8) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "32";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "1600";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "50";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 8 && vektventilasjon < 9) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "31";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "1860";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "60";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 9 && vektventilasjon < 10) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "31";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "2015";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "65";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 10 && vektventilasjon < 12) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "30";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "2250";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "75";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 12 && vektventilasjon < 14) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "29";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "2610";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "90";
  } else if (vektventilasjon >= 14 && vektventilasjon < 16) {
    document.getElementById("frekv").value = "27";
    document.getElementById("minvol").value = "2700";
    document.getElementById("tv").value = "100";
  }
}


function callCalculations() {
  ageCalculate();
  estWeight();
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.4fr 1.2fr 1.4fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 5px 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "Blank Content Inputinfo" "Blank Content Suggested";
}

.Content {
  grid-area: Content;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.Inputinfo {
  grid-area: Inputinfo;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}

.Suggested {
  grid-area: Suggested;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

.Header {
  grid-area: Header;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

html,
header,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* Style the top navigation bar */

.topnav {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(21, 42, 67, 1), rgba(88, 159, 209, 1));
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: justify;
  clear: left;
  width: 125px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 2px;
}

input {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: justify;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}


/* Style the footer */

.footer {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Barneanestesi legemiddelkalkulator</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <h1>Velkommen til barneanestesi legemiddelkalkulatoren!</h1>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="Content">
      <span class="Ventilasjon">
      <p><b><u>Ventilasjon</u></b></p>
      <label for="tv"><b>Tidalvolum:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="tv" name="tv"<br>
      <label for="frekv"><b>Frekvens:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="frekv" name="frekv"><br>
      <label for="minvol"><b>Min volum:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="minvol" name="minvol"><br>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="Inputinfo">
      <label for="gutt"><i class="material-icons">male</i><b>Gutt</b></label>
      <input type="radio" id="gutt" name="gender" value="Gutt">
      <label for="jente"><i class="material-icons">female</i><b>Jente</b></label>
      <input type="radio" id="jente" name="gender" value="Jente">
      <label for="initialer"><i class="material-icons">assignment</i><b>Initialer:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="initialer" name="initialer"><br>
      <label for="fdato"><i class="material-icons">cake</i><b>Fødselsdato:</b></label>
      <input type="date" id="fdato" name="fdato" oninput="callCalculations()" required><br>
      <label for="diagnose"><i class="material-icons">search</i><b>Diagnose:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="diagnose" name="diagnose"><br>
      <label for="operasjon"><i class="material-icons">local_hospital</i><b>Operasjon:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="operasjon" name="operasjon"><br>
      <label for="hoyde"><i class="material-icons">person_outline</i><b>Høyde (cm):</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="hoyde" name="hoyde"><br>
      <label for="Vekt"><i class="material-icons">monitor_weight</i><b>Vekt (kg):</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="vekt" name="vekt" value="" oninput="estVentilasjon()">
      <label for="Faste"><i class="material-icons">fastfood</i><b>Faste fra:</b></label>
      <input type="time" id="faste" name="faste">
    </div><br>
    <div class="Suggested">
      <label for="alder"><i class="material-icons">cake</i><b>Alder:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="alder" name="alder">
      <label for="estvekt"><i class="material-icons">monitor_weight</i><b>Estimert vekt:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="estvekt" name="estvekt">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./ba.js"></script>

  <div class="footer">

  </div>
```

---

Unrelated: It's best to reduce problems like this to their bare minimum. In the end this is a text input and an event handler, which could be posted as just a few lines of HTML and JS.

Cutting down a problem helps people understand the actual issues--there was a lot of code here, almost all of which is completely unrelated to the underlying issue.

FWIW, my path to resolving the issue was to first look at the event handler you called out in your post. As soon as I saw it was checking a value set somewhere else, I was reasonably sure it was either grabbing the value early, or less likely, some weird race condition.

Then I searched the code for where the value was set and saw it was set either on document load or worse, just inline with the rest of the JS (and didn't have to search far since it was right there ;)

One thing you can do to track stuff like this down is to put a sanity-check `console.log` of the value you think should be changing in the event handler. Once you see it never changes, take a step back and try to figure out why. This is almost always easier with a small, clean, minimal example.

Comment: How embaressing, so simple. Thank you for taking the time to explain it further and showing me how to do it. I wasn't aware that the var should be inside the function.

Comment: @Veritaas I added some additional tips/etc. regarding tracking down problems and asking questions in general--happy to help.